# Strange behavior of CHM project

Tags: css, chm, helpfile

Anybody can help me with a strange problem I am having with my CHM based project?

I took an existing CHM file and deconstructed the file using WinCHM. After that I added some new pages and compiled the project. The CHM file was created and everything looked great so far.

After that I put the entire folder (where the original CHM file was deconstructed) into SVN. When I opened the folder the next time I see that all the original formatting from the html pages is lost.

I cant seem to find a reason why. The css files are okay and i have not changed that at all. I know that finding a solution to this (or determining the problem)  may not be easy for you guys with so little information.

But can you guys at least tell me what the problem might be?? We are talking possibilities that is all.

Comment: Is it just the new pages that you added that have lost their formatting, or all pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you are in different directories when running, so CHM compiler doesn't get a proper understanding of the CHM root ? E.g. you now run a batchfile via a shortcut instead of changing to the proper dir ? (either by cmd.exe or direct link?)y

If that is not it, try looking at it with some other CHM viewer (easier on non Windows, but e.g. kchmviewer builds for windows exist too). Sometimes they give more error information (but sometimes only in the console window)

Then update your question with what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Hi Marco...thanks for your answer...the problem was that the stylesheets, images and scripts were not in the same folder as the html files. I have a separate related question which I have put up after this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so simple that I am surprised that it did not occur to me. The directories stylesheets, scripts and images are not in the same folder as the html files. These should be in the same folder.